# How to pass associative array(Index by tables) as parameter in PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with PostgreSQL function. I need to pass it as parameter an associative array (Index by tables) in PostgreSQL function.
Can somebody help me?

As I know we can't declare it as "`TYPE table_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER(10) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;`" in Postgresql. 
But What will be the better concept to replace "`TABLE OF NUMBER(10) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;`" in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Use an integer array `int[]`

Comment: As I am using char[] as a parameters in function, do you know how we can assign OUT parameters to char[].